# Ext JS: Scroll reset on Tab Change

Tags: extjs, scroll, extjs4.1

I'm using Ext JS v4.2.1 to draw a Tab panel in Screen and show some content -that can get quite big- in each tab. For that, Iuse something like this:

```
var createTab = function (tabName, panelName){
                    return {xtype: 'container',
                            title: tabName,
                            autoScroll: true,
                            layout: {
                                type: 'vbox',
                                align: 'stretch'
                            },
                            items: [
                                {
                                    title: panelName,
                                    items: [Ext.create( 'MyLongView' )]
                                }
                            ]};
            };

var tabPanel = new Ext.tab.Panel({
            renderTo: 'testDiv',
            flex: 1,
            border: false,
            itemId: 'tabPanel',
            items: [createTab('First Tab', 'First Panel'),
                    createTab('Second Tab', 'Second Panel')]
        });
```

When I tried that code **in Internet Explorer, each Tab Change resets the scroll position to the top**, a Bug that doesn't happen nor in Chrome or in Firefox. To reproduce it, follow this steps in an IE Window:

1. Create a Tab Panel, with to Tabs inside them.
2. In the first Tab, scroll down to the bottom.
3. Then, select the Second Tab.
4. Finally, return to the first tab. You'll see that the scroll that you left in the bottom is now in the top.

The expected behavior is that the scroll stays where you left it. Searching through Sencha forums, I found that they suggest the use of `hideMode: 'offsets'` but that doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

PS: I [created a Fiddle to show the bug](http://jsfiddle.net/dZYwL/8/). Please, only try that on IE (I don't know why it doesn't work on Chrome/Firefox).

Comment: Are you trying to PREVENT the scroll? Or do you want all browsers to scroll to the top? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I edited the Post to make it more clear

Comment: You say you're using 4.2.1, but used tag `extjs4.1`. Which one is correct? I remember there was a bug causing the behaviour you're describing, but afaik it was fixed with 4.2.x

Comment: I'm using Ext JS version 4.2.1. I have updated the Fiddle to reflect the right version, and the Bug is still there